# VBA for each loop reference previous and upcoming item

Tags: vba, excel

A rookie question.

The code below is given as an example, thus I am not referring to a specific case.

When doing a loop as below I can easily reference previous and upcoming items:

```
for i=1 to 10 
    for j = 1 to 10
        cells(i,j) = cells(i+1,j)
    next j
next i
```

How could I do the above with the code below?

```
dim rng, loopCell as Range
set rng = range(...)

for each loopCell in rng
    loopCell = UPCOMING OR PREVIOUS loopCell
next loopCell
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the offset property. Syntax is `.Offset(rowindex, column index)`

```
for each loopCell in rng
    loopCell = loopcell.Offset(-1, 0)
next loopCell
```

For Previous

Or

```
for each loopCell in rng
    loopCell = loopcell.Offset(1, 0)
next loopCell
```

For Next

Hope that helps

Answer (score 5):

The solution proposed by *FairlyLegit* is fine if **rng** is a nice compact rectangular range.  If **rng** is a disjoint group of cells, getting the previous cell is a bit tricky:

```
Sub dural()
    Dim rng As Range, r As Range, rPrevious As Range
    Set rng = Range("A1,C5,F7")
    For Each r In rng
        If rPrevious Is Nothing Then
        Else
            If r.Value = rPrevious.Value Then
                MsgBox r.Address & " has the same value as " & rPrevious.Address
            End If
        End If
        Set rPrevious = r
    Next r
End Sub
```